# Bring all windows of the same application to front by one key striking on Linux?

Tags: linux, window-manager

The question branched from [Bring to front all windows for a certain application in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/113162/bring-to-front-all-windows-for-a-certain-application-in-windows-7)

I often use some applications with multiple windows like ddd on Linux with icewm. I'll be very handy if there is a way I can bring all its windows to front just by hitting some key combinations.

Comment: Depends - what window manager?

Comment: As I've mentioned, icewm. But if you know any other wm can do this, please let me know. Thanks.